# Software for testing relational algebra

Tags: relation-algebra

Does anyone know of any software to let you test relational algebra queries? By this I don't mean a database such as MySQL, something where the query can be input in some for of mathematical notation instead of SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure how your supposed to "test" queries without an underlying data set to compare expected results to - in which case an RDBMS would be exactly what you need. Are you looking for a syntax checker?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any experience with programming languages such as Haskell or any of the ML-variants you could just use lists and map/filter/fold. Testing queries could then be achieved by using a testing framework such as QuickCheck (assuming you by "test" mean something like checking the result of a "query" satisfy some properties).

Answer (score 1):

There is Relational: http://ltworf.github.io/relational/

It uses the relational algebra syntax and is available on windows and linux.